# What means the expression "$\Bbb R$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, convention

The expression of the title seems to assert that $\Bbb R$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ but I cant see how this make sense, it is surely some kind of convention that I dont know.

I must suppose that $\Bbb R$ is the set of $x\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $x=\langle x,0,\ldots,0\rangle$ or something like this?

Can someone clarify this question? Thank you.

Comment: It's definitely sloppy language. It would be helpful to know more about the context to be sure what is meant.

Comment: Probably means that, indeed. But where did you read it?

Comment: @ClementC. it is from the book _Analysis I_ of Amann and Escher, but I dont remember that such convention was stated in the book :(

Comment: You still haven't given us a context - in what chapter? What is being discussed at the time? Give us an actual context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews chapter about basic topological concepts, after firsts steps on continuity, page 240.

Comment: I think your interpretation is very likely to be what was meant.  $\Bbb R$ is trivially homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\times\{0\}\times\cdots\times\{0\}$ and the image space is closed in the larger space.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is, in that context, likely correct. It's very sloppy, however, and not conventional. There is no real reason to pick one embedding of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R^n$ as "primary."

Comment: This make sense if you build it up from linear algebra with the convention of e_1, e_2, e_3,....

Comment: That is the canonical embedding and for sure this is what is meant. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from the context of the book the meaning of "$\Bbb R$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$" it is what I supposed it would be. Let define the projection

$$\pi: \Bbb K^n\to \Bbb K^{n-j},\; \langle a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\rangle\mapsto \langle a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n\rangle$$

then $\pi^{-1}(0)=\Bbb K^{j}$, under this "embedding" of $\Bbb K^j$ in $\Bbb K^n$ we have that

$$\Bbb K^j\text{ in }\Bbb K^n:=\Bbb K^j\times\underbrace{\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\cdots\times\{0\}}_{n-j\text{ times}}$$

P.S.: I opened the question with the hope that this convention could be standard, this is the reason why in first place I dont provided more details, sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, if you take the embedding where you map $\mathbb{R}$ to one of the canonical coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the image is a closed set. However, it's important to note that not all embeddings of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ have this property!

A good example is embedding $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and by extension $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n \geq 2$) as the unit circle about the origin missing one point. Since the missing point is a limit point, the set is not closed.

The easiest way to see this is possible is to use $f(x) = 2 \tan^{-1}(x)$ to map the entire real line to the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$ bijectively, and then interpreting this as an angular coordinate, fixing the radial coordinate to $1$. The final embedding $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ would then be:

$$
f(x) = \langle \cos(2 \tan^{-1}(x)), \sin(2 \tan^{-1}(x)) \rangle
$$

in rectangular coordinates, and the missing point would be $\langle -1, 0 \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are pages 239,240,241 in translation, from the second edition.

Where does it say $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n?$

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I simplified the question, the text says instead "$\Bbb K^k$ is closed in $\Bbb K^n$" in page 140. But it is the same to consider the case that I posted.

Comment: @Masacroso evidently page 240 rather than 140, Example 2.22(b), the context being Theorem 2.20 on page 239.

Comment: Man, ok, I had a typo. I posted the page some time ago in the comments of the question. Yes, it is 240.

Comment: @Masacroso if you plan on pulling this sort of thing in future, get a scanner of some sort so that you can post two or three pages, and we can see what is really there, along with nearby material that may explain.